# What does alpha in smoothing stand for

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing, smoothing

I want to apply Gaussian smoothing to a dataset and came across the `smth.gaussian` function in R. That besides the numerical input data requires two parameters:

> **window**    : the length of the smoothing window, if an integer, represents
>   number of items, else, if a value between 0 and 1, represents the
>   proportion of the input vector
>
> **alpha** : parameter to determine the breadth of the gaussian window,
>   yielding more or less sensitive smoothing characteristics

According to this explanation `window` tells where smoothing has to be applied whereas `alpha` tells how much smoothing has to be applied. However I don't know how I should actually interpret this `alpha`. For example what does it say when alpha = 0.5 or alpha = 10? In addition, what is the upper boundary of this `alpha` value?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some more details about that `smth.gaussian` is. I used R quite a lot, but this is a first time I hear about this function.

Comment: This question is answered in the documentation at https://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/gausswin.html: "alpha is inversely proportional to the width of the window."